# Angular controller scope variable not updated

Tags: angularjs

I have this code which permit to signin via Social Networks:

I have an HTML page which calls facebookSubscrib, googlePlusSubscribe function on click, that works:

```
KecooApp.controller('homeCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', 'configuration',  '$state', '$modal',
    function ($scope, $rootScope, configuration, $state, $modal) {


   } 
]);



 KecooApp.controller('signupCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', 'configuration', '$state', '$modal', 'Facebook', 'googleplus', 'linkedin',               '$state',
     function ($scope, $rootScope, configuration, $state, $modal, Facebook, googleplus, linkedin, $state) {


         $scope.RSUserInfo = {};
            
         $scope.check =  function() {
             console.log($scope.RSUserInfo);
         }
    
    
         $scope.RSUserInfoParse = function(provider,data) {
              switch(provider) {
                 case "facebook":
                     break;
                 case "google":
                     console.log(data);
                     RSUserInfo={};
                     RSUserInfo.lastname=data.family_name;
                     RSUserInfo.firstname=data.given_name;
                     return(RSUserInfo);
                     break;
                 case "linkedin":
                     break;
                 case "twitter":
                     break;
              }   
         }
    
    
         $scope.facebookSubscribe = function () {
             // From now on you can use the Facebook service just as Facebook api says
             Facebook.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
                 if (response.status === 'connected') {
                     $scope.FBloggedIn = true;
                     Facebook.api('/me', function (response) {
                         $scope.user = response;
                         $scope.RSUserInfo=$scope.RSUserInfoParse("facebook",response);
                     });
                 } else {
                     $scope.FBloggedIn = false;
                     Facebook.login(function (response) {
                         Facebook.api('/me', function (response) {
                             $scope.user = response;
                                  $scope.RSUserInfo=$scope.RSUserInfoParse("facebook",response);
                         });
                     });
                 }
             });
             $state.go('app.signup-step1');
         };

         $scope.googlePlusSubscribe = function () {
             googleplus.login().then(function (authResult) {
                 googleplus.getUser().then(function (user) {                    
                     console.log($scope.RSUserInfoParse("google",user,$scope.RSUserInfo));
                     $state.go('app.signup-step1');
                 });
             }, function (err) {
             });
       
         };


         $scope.linkedinSubscribe = function () {
             data = linkedin.authorizeLinkedin();
                  $scope.RSUserInfo=$scope.RSUserInfoParse("linkedin",data);
         }

         $scope.twitterSubscribe = function () {
             Digits.logIn()
                     .done($scope.twitterSuccess) /*handle the response*/
                     .fail();
             $state.go('app.signup-step1');
         }

         $scope.twitterSuccess = function (reponse) {
             $scope.RSUserInfo$scope.RSUserInfoParse("twitter",response);
             $state.go('app.signup-step1');
         }

   
     }
 ]);
```

When googlePlusSubscribe is fired the function is called RSUserInfo (in google section on RSUserInfoParse) is set but $scope.RSUserInfo is already empty.

How can I make this work?

Comment: scope.RSInfo  It is not in your script

Comment: You are not setting $scope.RSUserInfo anywhere.It is always empty.And you are not using 'user' object in your getUser() function result

Comment: And you're injecting $state twice in the controller.